# Doctrine 2 can't find entities classes

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I can't get Doctrine to find my entities classes which lays in www/entities/..

I'm keeping getting the error "**Fatal error: Class 'Event' not found in /home/dxs/public_html/create-event.php on line 7**".. And i feel like i tried almost everything..

The file which im calling is:

### create-event.php:

```
<?php
require_once("bootstrap.php");
require_once("entities/Event.php");
$name = $argv[1];
$description = $argv[2];

$event1 = new Event;
$event1->setName("test");
$event1->setDescription("testdesc");

$entityManager->persist($event1);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Created Event with ID " . $event1->getId() . "\n";
```

### Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

if(!class_exists("Doctrine\Common\Version", FALSE))

{

    require_once 'bootstrap_doctrine.php';

}
```

### Bootstrap

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

if(!class_exists("Doctrine\Common\Version", FALSE))
{

    require_once 'bootstrap_doctrine.php';

}
```

### Updated bootstrap doctrine

```
 <?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

require_once "Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php";

Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();
$cl = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__);
$cl->register();

$isDevMode = true;

$path = array(__DIR__.'/entities');
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($path, $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'dxs',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'dbname' => 'db'

);
// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);   

AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("/usr/local/lib/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php");
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace("Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint", "/usr/local/lib/php/Doctrine/Symfony");
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace("MyProject\Annotations", ROOT.DS.'www');

$reader = new AnnotationReader();
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('dummy');
```

What am i doing wrong?

### Updated event class with annotations

Event class

```
<?php
namespace Entities\Event;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Table(name="events")
 * @Annotations\Event
 */
class Event
{
    /** @ORM\Id @GeneratedValue
     *  @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotEmpty
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

Comment: I include this in my event entity class

namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

Comment: Thanks for adding the entity - would be good to add the new error message to your post update as well so that the problem being solved is clear to viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this doc
[doctrine annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) 
for the correct way to define your entity.

E.g. you need the `* @ORM\Entity` in your opening comment.

Comment: I followed the doctrine annotations but i still get the error:

Entities\Event is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in /usr/local/lib/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:147

Comment: This might not be the actual solution, but certainly if you want to use the validation constraints (@Assert\NotEmpty) you need to include them in your project. E.g. the Doctine docs you took that line from has "use Symfony\Component\Validation\Constraints AS Assert;" In your case you should probably remove the @Assert until you get it working without.

Comment: I see it is in your autoloader but you have missed the use statement from the Entity.

Comment: I got it working, turns out that my server was looking in the wrong folder for the entities, i had an entity folder two places.. but thank you for the help

Comment: @Saggo How do you work it out? I have the same problem, I try using the --path argument…

Comment: @Saggo I got it working, using : notation instead of \.